# VW Jetta parking brake loose after rear brakes replaced. Is it related?

Tags: brakes, vw, jetta, parking-brake, emergency-brakes

I had my 2007 VW Jetta rear brakes replaced, including the rotors. When I picked up my car I noticed the parking brake was very loose, I almost have to take it at a 90 degree angle for the brake to hold the car. Before I took my car for service, it would only take a few clicks to use the parking brake.

Car shop manager is saying they are two different systems, and that I have to pay to fix the looseness. Isn't it too much coincidence the parking brake was loose after brake service? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you normally use the parking brake? There may be something wrong with the caliper or cable.

Answer (score 3):

**They are lying to you.**

The cables attach to the same calipers they worked on.

[image]

This leads me to believe they either forgot to reconnect them or failed to adjust it properly.

I would suggest you take it back to them and demand they fix it properly or take it to a different mechanic.

Comment: On a 2007 model there ought to be a handbrake return spring which fits in the holes shown in the parts arrowed yellow and green.  It sounds as though this hasn't been refitted.

Comment: The part number for this spring is something like 5K0 615 295 and 5K0 615 296 for the other side?